# Is there a way to log flyway "select" statements

Tags: flyway

I am using flyway to execute Oracle SQL. I can get debug statements using -x but not for select statements.

For eg: insert queries returns like below in the logs
Insert into xxx
Update count: x

But select queries didnt return any logs on outputs. I tried writing a custom slf4j logger on top of flyway but no use. Any thoughts on this please ?